# Fatal error: Out of memory PHP

Tags: php, memory, timeout

I am not sure why this was working fine last night and this morning I am getting

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1611137024) (tried to allocate
>   1610350592 bytes) in /home/twitcast/public_html/system/index.php on
>   line 121

The section of code being ran is as follows

```
function podcast()
  {
            $fetch = new server();
            $fetch->connect("TCaster");
            $collection = $fetch->db->shows;

            // find everything in the collection
            $cursor = $collection->find();

            if($cursor->count() > 0)
            {
                $test = array();
                // iterate through the results
                while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                    $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
                }
                $i = 0;
                foreach($test as $d) {

                for ( $i = 0; $i <= 3; $i ++) {
                $url = $d["streams"][$i];   
                $xml = file_get_contents( $url );
                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                $doc->loadXML( $xml); // $xml = file_get_contents( "http://www.c3carlingford.org.au/podcast/C3CiTunesFeed.xml")

                // Initialize XPath    
                $xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);
                // Register the itunes namespace
                $xpath->registerNamespace( 'itunes', 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');

                $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');    
                    foreach( $items as $item) {
                        $title = $xpath->query( 'title', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
                        $published = strtotime($xpath->query( 'pubDate', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue);
                        $author = $xpath->query( 'itunes:author', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
                        $summary = $xpath->query( 'itunes:summary', $item)->item(0)->nodeValue;
                        $enclosure = $xpath->query( 'enclosure', $item)->item(0);
                        $url = $enclosure->attributes->getNamedItem('url')->value;

                    $fname = basename($url);
                    $collection = $fetch->db->shows_episodes;

                    $cursorfind = $collection->find(array("internal_url"=>"http://twitcatcher.russellharrower.com/videos/$fname"));
                    if($cursorfind->count() < 1)
                    {


                        $copydir = "/home/twt/public_html/videos/";
                        $data = file_get_contents($url);
                        $file = fopen($copydir . $fname, "w+");

                        fputs($file, $data);

                        fclose($file);
                        $collection->insert(array("show_id"=> new MongoId($d["_id"]),"stream"=>$i,"episode_title"=>$title, "episode_summary"=>$summary,"published"=>$published,"internal_url"=>"http://twitcatcher.russellharrower.com/videos/$fname"));

                        echo "$title <br> $published <br> $summary <br> $url<br><br>\n\n";
                    }




                }

            }
            }
            }
```

line 121 is

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: @khanahk $data = file_get_contents($url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add 1.6GB of memory usage for a single PHP thread? While you can increase the memory limit, my strong advice is to look at another way of doing what you want.

Probably the easiest solution: you can use CURL to request a byte range of the source file (using Curl is wiser than get_file_contents anyway, for remote files). You can get 100K ata  time, write to the local file then got the next 100k and appeand to the file etc, until the entire file is pulled in.

You may also do something with streams, but it gets a little more complex. This may be your only option if the remote server won't let you get part of a file by bytes.

Finally there's Linux commands such as wget, run through exec(), if your server has permissions.

Answer (score 0):

[Memory Limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) - take a look at this directive. Suppose that is what you need.

or you may try to use `copy` instead of reading file to memory (which is video file, as I understand so there is nothing strange that it takes a lot of memory):

```
$copydir = "/home/twt/public_html/videos/";
copy($url, $copydir . $fname);
```

Looks like last night opened file were smaller)

Comment: strange cos they are all HD files I will give that a go and see what happens, atm i am trying wget

Comment: @RussellHarrower suppose copy will work good enough. Or wget. Basically, anything that will not read a file to memory. I just translated those bytes into something human readable and appears that you are reading a file which takes more than 1.6GB - putting whole that file into a memory (file_get_contents do this) is not what you need for sure)